# Running blackberry app into multiple emulators at the same time

Tags: sockets, blackberry, blackberry-simulator

I am developing a blackberry application and I'm trying to get to devices to communicate. I am trying out the SocketDemo app and it shed light into the socket process (which is no different from any other platform so far).

Only problem is I can't test the app since I can't get the app into two different emulators. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not need to hook the second simulator into the debugger (for breakpoint setting, etc), then getting your application to run simultaneously on two simulators can be done fairly easily.

Build your application, and run it from the JDE; standard procedure.

Then, outside the JDE, start another simulator (it cannot be the same one), and, when that's up and running, choose FILE->LOAD JAVA APPLICATION from the second simulator's window menu. Select the .COD of the application you just built. The application will then be installed onto the second simulator, and will either start automatically, or you can start it by clicking on its icon (depending on how your project is set up).

With two simulators on the same machine, with applications that need to communicate through the network, it may be needed to change the ports in the .BAT file that launches the second simulator, before starting it -- otherwise, the second simulator may not be able to bind to the same ports on the machine.

Indeed, with some simulator models, you will not be able to do this unless the second simulator is from a different simulator package (different directory), because the process grabs a lock when it runs.

If you are using a built-in simulator package that only contains one simulator, you can download a second simulator, ideally a different model, from RIM's developer site: http://www.blackberry.com/developers/downloads/simulators/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing different JDE's and trying to run emulators from them?

Comment: Why would I need to install different JDE's to run an app into two separate emulators? If I can run multiple emulators at the same time... Shouldn't it just be app-loading related?